# Django Social Auth - Google: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'

Tags: python, django, django-users, python-social-auth, django-custom-user

I am receiving this error when trying to login via google, I've tried just about everything I can think of and similar issues on SO don't seem to help. I have a custom user model setup as such:

## models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
class Departments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AlluredUser(AbstractUser):
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Departments)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import AlluredUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AlluredUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AlluredUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

## Social Auth Pipeline

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

## Error Traceback

```
AttributeError at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/complete/google-oauth2/?state=8XLcbxz6sPSPOwJfOIXWOud88UJ5YtL2&code=4/twHRVLHTMzBV99K-VvektvJfjGuJYGBvqi254dWTuA2dLmbNFw3fIp8l5pdYSqKK89ONPGrxInG39pH8Wf-fpas&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20openid&authuser=0&hd=allured.com&session_state=2403f8348307b18b8ab460026d3c88b1b18d759f..5dbb&prompt=none

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['user.apps.UserConfig',
 'issue_tracker.apps.IssueTrackerConfig',
 'ytd_reports.apps.YtdReportsConfig',
 'stats.apps.StatsConfig',
 'scheduler.apps.SchedulerConfig',
 'submissions.apps.SubmissionsConfig',
 'dash_app.apps.DashAppConfig',
 'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'social_django']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
 'dashboard.middleware.loginRequired.LoginRequiredMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py" in wrapper
  49.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\views.py" in complete
  33.                        *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jsarko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\actions.py" in do_complete
  71.                                          social_user.provider)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the custom user model I created since I didn't have this problem beforehand. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error message in the post title doesn't match the error message on the dpaste link.

Comment: Also, it's much better to provide the error traceback as plain text in the post, instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: My mistake, I updated my post. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Hey, did you eventually fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error on the link doesn't match what you mention in the title.
For the traceback, the solution is just to add this:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```